# Handsontable editing nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, handsontable, eventhandler

I am using handsontable and am having trouble getting the "beforeChange" and "afterChange" events to fire consistently, which I'm hoping use to commit updates to the database. I am using the following code (version 0.16.1):

HTML:

```
<div id="table"></div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var data = [{
  id: 5,
  name: 'Sedan',
  price: 2000,
  tags: ['pink', 'purple']
}, {
  id: 6,
  name: 'Truck',
  price: 1500,
  tags: ['green', 'blue']
}, {
  id: 6,
  name: 'SUV',
  price: 1500,
  tags: null
}];

var writeMessage = function(msg) {
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  var div = document.createElement('DIV');
  div.innerHTML = msg;
  output.insertBefore(div, output.firstChild);
  console.log(msg);
};
var tableDiv = document.getElementById("table");
this.table = new Handsontable(tableDiv, {
  data: data,
  colHeaders: ["id", "name", "price", "tags"],
  columns: [{
    data: "id"
  }, {
    data: "name"
  }, {
    data: "price"
  }, {
    data: "tags"
  }],
  beforeChange: function(changes, source) {
    writeMessage("beforeChange: " + changes + ": " + source);
  },
  afterChange: function(changes, source) {
    writeMessage("After Change fired: " + changes);
    if (!changes) {
      return;
    }
    var i, idx, key, newVal, modelID;
    for (i = 0; i < changes.length; i++) {
      idx = changes[i][0];
      key = changes[i][1];
      newVal = changes[i][3];
      modelID = this.getDataAtRow(idx)[0];
      writeMessage("New value: " + key + ": " + newVal);
    }
  }
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GjzrdX?editors=0010

The event handlers fire when I'm editing the text and number fields and for the when tags are null, but do not fire for data objects with tag arrays (e.g. pink,purple; green,blue). How do I get the events to fire for the tag cells without modifying the data structure? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you are facing a bug here when trying to put an Array in a Cell but I cannot find anywhere in the handsontable documentation or any thread in their GitHub mentioning this issue... IMO, putting an Array in a Cell is suppose to be use as Source and not Data, which result in a cell that you can't edit (hence the events afterChange/beforeChange not triggered). In your example the third line is working because of the 'null' value which is not an Array.

Anyway, the only workaround I managed to do for you is to modify your data **after** you define your data structure (in order to respect your condition, but I strongly advice do modify them anyway because you will need to do that eventually).

Assuming that your *tags* can only contain two values :

```
var data1 = [];
for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++) {
  if (data[i].tags != null) {
    var temp = data[i].tags[0];
    temp = temp.concat(',');
    temp = temp.concat(data[i].tags[1]);
  } else var temp = null;
  data1.push({ id: data[i].id, name: data[i].name, price: data[i].price, tags: temp });
}
```

If the length of your Arrays *tags* can be more than that, just do a second loop to cover it.

See your code [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qavgxq?editors=0010) with this solution implemented

You then can use data1 to load your table. If you need to save your data after modification, you can use a similar function to reverse it into your original data structure.

Comment: thank you. I was hoping to avoid the extra loop to handle the tags' array-to-string conversion, but agree with you that this seems to be the only way, and is certainly not a deal breaker. Handsontable has been an amazing resource, and this is a minor workaround. I appreciate you taking the time to investigate this.